# tampoco and me gusta

Tags: gramática, negación

I want to ask a question about using the word *tampoco* with *me gusta*.

I was asked to fill in the blank for the following sentence:

```
A mí ______ me gustan, pero a mis hermanos les gustan mucho.
```

I first thought it would be *tambien* but then it made no sense given the sentence had *pero* involved in the next clause.

I realised the only other possibility would be *tampoco*, but the sentence:

> A mí tampoco me gustan, pero a mis hermanos les gustan mucho

appeared to mean to me

> I like them neither, but my brothers like them a lot

which made no sense at all.

I thought the sentence should have been

> A mí tampoco no me gustan, pero a mis hermanos les gustan mucho

i.e. to negate the verb *gustan* but it doesn't appear to work.

Why do we not negate the verb *gustar* with '*no*' when using it with *tampoco* to imply negation?

Comment: The correct translation is: **I don't like them either.**

Comment: @Lambie but how would you infer that the verb _gustar_ is negated without the _no_ placed ahead of it? It might be an intricacy of the Spanish language but there are few that I am aware of aside of _ser_ and _estar_ so this was initially confusing to me until I saw the answer below.

Comment: I was correcting your incorrect translation, that's all. There are no inferences here. You just have to memorize it: Me gusta|| no me gusta||tampoco me gusta where that third one means: I don't like it **either**.

Comment: Oh my apologies! Yes, I stand corrected. Thanks for the help! @Lambie

Answer (score 4):

There are some adverbs of negation which, in certain circumstances, do not need the *no*.

https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/doble-negacion-no-vino-nadie-no-hice-nada-no-tengo-ninguna

explains it much, much better than I can so here is the entry. My rendering of it into English follows it.

> En español existe un esquema particular de negación, que permite combinar el adverbio *no* con la presencia de otros elementos que tienen también sentido negativo.

> Los adverbios *nunca, jamás, tampoco*, los indefinidos *nadie, nada, ninguno*, la locución *en la/mi/tu/su vida* y los grupos que contienen la palabra *ni* aparecen siempre en oraciones de sentido negativo. Si estos elementos van antepuestos al verbo, este no va acompañado del adverbio de negación no: ***Nunca** voy al teatro; Él **tampoco** está de acuerdo; **Jamás** lo haré; **Nadie** lo sabe; **Nada** de lo que dice tiene sentido; **Ninguno** de ellos es actor; **En su vida** lo conseguirá; **Ni** su padre lo perdonaría*. Pero si van pospuestos al verbo, este debe ir necesariamente precedido del adverbio *no*: ***No** voy **nunca** al teatro; Él **no** está de acuerdo **tampoco**; **No** lo haré **jamás**; **No** lo sabe **nadie**; **No** tiene sentido **nada** de lo que dice; **No** es actor **ninguno** de ellos; **No** lo conseguirá **en su vida**; **No** lo perdonaría **ni** su padre*. La concurrencia de esas dos «negaciones» no anula el sentido negativo del enunciado, sino que lo refuerza.

My translation follows. Note that I am neither a trained linguist nor a professional translator so the Spanish version should always be taken as definitive.

> In Spanish there is a particular format of negation which allows for the combination of the adverb *no* with other elements which also have a negative meaning.

> The adverbs *nunca, jamás, tampoco*, the pronouns *nadie, nada, ninguno*, the phrases *en la/mi/tu/su vida* and groups which contain the word *ni* always appear in sentences with a negative sense. If these element are placed before the verb then that it not accompanied with the adverb *no*. ***Nunca** voy al teatro; Él **tampoco** está de acuerdo; **Jamás** lo haré; **Nadie** lo sabe; **Nada** de lo que dice tiene sentido; **Ninguno** de ellos es actor; **En su vida** lo conseguirá; **Ni** su padre lo perdonaría*. But if they follow the verb then it must be preceded by the adverb *no*. ***No** voy **nunca** al teatro; Él **no** está de acuerdo **tampoco**; **No** lo haré **jamás**; **No** lo sabe **nadie**; **No** tiene sentido **nada** de lo que dice; **No** es actor **ninguno** de ellos; **No** lo conseguirá **en su vida**; **No** lo perdonaría **ni** su padre*. The co-occurrence of these two negative forms does not cancel the negative effect but reinforces it.

Answer (score 2):

*Tampoco* is always used after another negation. You need a negative sentence before the one you posted, for example:

> Me dijo que no le gustan los dulces. A mi tampoco me gustan, pero a
> mis hermanos les gustan mucho.

There's also another way to use it correctly without the previous sentence:

> A mi no me gustan tampoco, pero a mis hermanos les gustan mucho.

https://www.rae.es/dpd/tampoco